# Default value for a property in Ant

Tags: java, ant

I have an Ant target which is triggering a Java class and few properties are set as part of this target.

```
<target name='test-target'>
  <java fork="true" classname="MyClass" failonerror="true">
     <sysproperty key="numOfEntries" value="${numOfEntries}" />
  </java>
</target>
```

If the user is not using `-DnumOfEntries` when running Ant, the value is being set to the literal string `${numOfEntries}`. How can I set a default value for the numOfEntries property in case user is not passing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to solve this problem:

```
<property name="numOfEntries" value=10/>
<target name='test-target'>
   <java fork="true" classname="MyClass" failonerror="true">
      <sysproperty key="numOfEntries" value="${numOfEntries}" />
   </java>
</target>
```

If user is not setting numOfEntries default value 10 will be used.

Comment: Could you mark this as "Accepted", so that the question shows as answered?